# Sinatra: how to use helpers in dynamically generated routes?

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra

I create a route for each product from database with following code:

```
Products.all.each do |product|
  get "/#{product.title.latinize}"
  end
end

class String
  def latinize
    self
  end
end #or with helpers
```

which raises **NoMethodError: undefined method `latinize' for "hello":String**.

How to use helpers (or class's extensions as seen here) from dynamically generated routes in Sinatra?

Comment: I may be wrong, have you tried to define it before using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you are defining the `latinize` method after you are generating the routes. Move to above the `Product.all` section.

Comment: That's true, thank you! Moving them up in the code worked both for helpers and classes. I though Sinatra took care of this somehow.